# Retrieving all users of a specific permission in Laravel 5 / Entrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I retrieve the users of a specific permission in Entrust for Laravel 5.0.

```
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;    

$permission = Permission::find(1);
$roles = $permission->roles;
$users = $roles->users;
```

I know the code doesn't work... Just an example.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$users = User::permission('edit articles')->get(); // Returns only users with the permission 'edit articles'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Entrust before, but I looked through the code on GitHub.

`Permission` has a `belongsToMany` for roles.

`Role` has a `belongsToMany` for users.

Therefore you should be able to chain the commands like so:

```
$permission = Permission::find(1);
$users = $permission->roles()->users;
```

If you are planning on chaining relationships, you should add braces onto the relationship name.

Comment: ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$users

Comment: Honestly sounds like you've got something wrong with your installation, or maybe you're overwriting the methods?

Comment: I don't know, but I've always used Entrust and it's always worked. But yeah I don't know how to do what I asked here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ntzm, I was able to figure out how to find all the users who have access to the Permission. Not sure if this will help anyone.

There are two different types of employees who has access to a permission. One from the roles and second is where the permission is given direction to them. I haven't used the direct one yet, but I do have roles that have access to permissions. Here's how I was able to get the users with a certain permission:

```
    $permission = Permission::findByName('edit posts');

    $employees = [];

    //Loop through each role.
    foreach($permission->roles as $r){
        $emps = $r->users;

        //Cycle through the users.
        foreach($emps as $e){
            $employees[] = $e;
        }
    }

    return $employees;
```

Hopefully this helped someone who also needed this. :)